# how to render html file in window/dialog box using activex control

Tags: c++, dom, html-parsing, activexobject, activex-documents

I am working on visual++ and trying to render a preview of a html file on a dialog box/Window created by me.
(just as we get preview pane on window explorer on hmlFile.html single click) .
I tried lot of search on google but resulted in un-success. 
I got idea from somewhere that it can be accomplished by using activex control. 
My project is already rendering  FileName.png image(i mean  already working for .png image) in the dialog box i created.

But now the next task is to make the preview render for .html files. I have no ideas of how to accomplish this task . any ideas ?? If by ActiveX Control ??
For ;png file the idea was to store the contents of .png file in the stream(which is generated by single button click on .png file) and then create decoder and then create bitmap source to 32bppHbitmap and then preview on preview pane/window created/dialog Box and i also know about .xml files -in this case we create a style sheet) but i dont' know how to do for html files ???

Any help ?? or good links ????

Answer (score 0):

The MFC library makes this rather easy. Here is a link to a sample program that uses MFC CHtmlView to create a browser:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177540(v=VS.80).aspx

Comment: You mean i need to add activeX control to my DialogBox/Created Window and host the Web Borwser inside that and then pass the html contents which are currently present in my IStream *m_FinalHTMLStream) and then i will have the html file preview  in my created dialogbox/created Window ??